# Can a GTK applet widget be instantiated through dbus?

Tags: python, c, gtk, d-bus

I just posted this:

[#274616: “Simple” gnome applets in Unity - stickynotes](https://askubuntu.com/a/274616/6808)

... where I could instantiate a Gnome 2 `bonobo` applet in a standalone window,

[image: invest-applet-unity-standalone]

... using `bonobo.ui.widget_new_control_from_objref` in a Python script - here is a snippet:

```
...
bcontrol = bonobo.activation.activate_from_id('OAFIID:Invest_Applet', 0, False)
buiwid = bonobo.ui.widget_new_control_from_objref(bcontrol, win.get_ui_container().corba_objref())
win.set_contents(buiwid)
...
```

I find this method extremely convenient, so I was wandering whether one could do something similar with `dbus` bindings; either from Python or from C?

(I would personally gather not - as far as I've read around, it seems `bonobo` was specifically intended for instantiating one application in another; while `dbus` currently just exchanges messages; however, I'd like to have it confirmed).

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, this is not possible. D-Bus is merely a message passing system and knows nothing about GUI's.